# Error con move_uploaded_file al subir una imagen

Tags: php, function, fastreport

Hola a todos gracias por acudir a mi llamado, antes de comenzar si la pregunta esta mal formulada o algo no cuadra sean libres de editar y mejorar esta pregunta...

Tengo la siguiente función para subir una imagen a una carpeta destinada

```
public static function uploadFile($file, string $type)
        {

            // path de la carpeta destino:
            $path = 'public/img/' . $type . '/';

            // Obtener el la extensión del archivo:
            $extension = pathinfo($file['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

            // Crear el nombre del archivo:
            $name = md5(time()) . '_' . time() . '_' . uniqid() . '.' . $extension;
            
            // Subir el archivo:
            $upload = move_uploaded_file($file['name'], $path . $name);

            // Retornar el nombre del archivo:
            return $name;
            
        }
```

Error que tengo es este:

`PHP Warning:  move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move 'C:\xampp\tmp\phpB9FD.tmp' to 'public/img/cover/ed844cb1c8e5d10dc792a5a3c5c253b8_1659589664_62eb54209f2d5.webp' in C:\Users\Doyun\Desktop\Anichuu\src\controllers\File.php on line 24`

¿A que se debe el error?

Comment: 1. La carpeta destino no existe

Comment: 2. La carpeta de destino no tiene permisos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La dirección donde guardaras la imagen  deber ser un ruta valida

Le estas pasando un ruta incompleta

Cambia esta linea :

```
// path de la carpeta destino:
 $path = $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] .'/public/img/' . $type . '/';
```